# g++ is giving "unresolved overloaded function type" with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Reduced to basic form, I'm trying to do something like this with a binary search tree:

```
template <class Item, class Key>
class bst
{
public:
    Item val;
    Key key;
    bst *left;
    bst *right;
private:
};

template <class Item, class Key, class Process, class Param>
void preorder_processing1(bst<Item, Key> *root, Process f, Param g)
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    f(root->val, g);
    preorder_processing1(root->left, f, g);
    preorder_processing1(root->right, f, g);
}

template <class Item, class Key>
void print_path(const bst<Item, Key>* root, const Key target)
{
    if (root->key != target)
    {
        cout << root->key << " " << root->val << endl;
        if (target < root->key)
            print_path(root->right, target);
        else
            print_path(root->left, target);
    }
    else
        cout << root->key << " " << root->val << endl;
}

template <class Item, class Key>
void print_if_leaf(const bst<Item, Key>* test_node, const bst<Item, Key>* root)
{
    if (test_node->right == NULL && test_node->left == NULL)
    {
        print_path(root, test_node->key);
        cout << endl;
    }
}

template <class Item, class Key>
void print_paths_bst(const bst<Item, Key>* root)
{
    preorder_processing1(root, print_if_leaf, root);
}
```

When I call print_paths_bst, I get this: `error: no matching function for call to ‘preorder_processing1(const bst<int, int>*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, const bst<int, int>*&)’`

I've tried forcing a cast on the preorder_processing1 call like

```
preorder_processing1(root, print_if_leaf<Item, Key>, root);
```

...but this also hasn't resolved the problem.

Does anyone see what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <class Item, class Key, class Process, class Param>
void preorder_processing1(bst<Item, Key> *root, Process f, Param g)
```

This needs to take a `const bst<Item, Key> *`

Additionally, your call to `f(root->val, g);`  will have problems - `root->val` isn't a `bst<Item, Key> const *`. You likely mean `f(root, g)`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. I missed the f(root, g) thing, good call. However, I'm still receiving the same compile error, this time with const: error: no matching function for call to ‘preorder_processing2(const bst<int, int>*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, const bst<int, int>*&)’

Comment: You'll need your `print_if_leaf<Item, Key>` variant.

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I've been working on this for a while. What exactly do you mean by that I'll need my print_if_leaf<Item, Key> variant?

Comment: @deeb: You said you already tried `preorder_processing1(root, print_if_leaf<Item, Key>, root);` - that's how you have to call it.

Comment: Seriously you have no idea how helpful this is, it's been one of those days.

Comment: @deeb: NP, that's what SO is for